# "Error Creating AVD. An error occurred while crating the AVD. See idea.log for details " Studio vers. 3.32 in Ubuntu vers. 18.04

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I can't create an AVD for a very famous error: "Error Creating AVD.
An error occurred while crating the AVD. See idea.log for details "with Anfroid Studio 3.3.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.

**I tried all the solutions present on stackoverflow** and not only but without success.

I attach the error and warning part of the idea.log file:

```
2019-03-27 11:07:28,756 [d thread 5]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/danielemod/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_28.ini 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,530 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd must not return null 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd must not return null
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.$$$reportNull$$$0(AvdOptionsModel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd(AvdOptionsModel.java:796)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:44)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 3.3.2  Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
2019-03-27 11:10:57,532 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: Android.RunAndroidAvdManager 
2019-03-27 11:11:52,979 [d thread 5]   WARN - dea.sdk.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by unlocking the ANDROID folder accesses with the terminal command: 
sudo chown [USER NAME] .android

suluzione trovata in:
[Unable to create Android Virtual Device in Android Studio 2.2 in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404980/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device-in-android-studio-2-2-in-ubuntu)

Comment: my problem wasn't exactly permissions, but this answer pointed me to the right path; my `~/.android/avd` folder was a symlink to an external drive which wasn't connected - I probably did it years ago, then stopped working with Android and forgot I did that trick to free up space in my `home` partition LOL