# An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details. When trying to duplicate a AVD

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

Creating the AVD and trying to duplicate it.

Getting this error: "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."

LOG:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getId()" because the return value of "com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd()" is null
at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.VirtualDevicePopUpMenuButtonTableCellEditor.lambda$newDuplicateItem$1(VirtualDevicePopUpMenuButtonTableCellEditor.java:141)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:374)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1028)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1072)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:759)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:918)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:791)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:624)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

Google fixes but only fix that worked is deleting all the existing AVDs

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error Creating AVD. An error occurred while crating the AVD. See idea.log for details " Studio vers. 3.32 in Ubuntu vers. 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375393/error-creating-avd-an-error-occurred-while-crating-the-avd-see-idea-log-for-d)