# How to fix ADV Error error while creating an ADV

Tags: android, android-studio

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getId()" because the return value of "com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd()" is null
at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.actionPerformed(BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.java:51)
at com.intellij.util.ui.StatusText$1.onClick(StatusText.java:91)
at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:59)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at com.intellij.ui.table.JBTable.processMouseEvent(JBTable.java:764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

I try to install Jdk 11 (LTS)
Install other system image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, I fixed it by following these steps https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7494016 but on the user/.android folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The actual problem seems to be related to the `~/.android/avd` folder, to be more precise. This answer isn't clear at all on that - just pasting a confusing answer from an OS-specific forum doesn't help much... but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55375393/102960) helped me find the root cause.

Comment: @igorsantos07 yes, the post you mention is basically doing the same. In my case it was related to permissions.